long time user MrBond 1year ban?
Can the moderators explain why Mr Bond was suddenly banned for a year?
Mr Bond has been a contributor for over 4 years. A constant source of frustration to users who don’t belong to mainstream Christianity.  I have flagged his questions and answers many times.
Was there ever a shorter ban imposed of Mr bond?  Was he admonished numerous times? Or did the moderator just whack with a heavy hand and no warning?

For confidentiality's sake, we don't discuss moderation actions taken against any particular user.  But in general, actionable flags will get a person banned and the general principle is to increase the ban lengths over time.
As for the comment thread, under this post, which I deleted because it was gonna probably descend into darkness - we haven't been stellar at enforcing our unique comment policy, but stackexchange doesn't really give us the tools for enforcing it either and leaves it at the discretion of the moderators.  We're the cleanup crew, we leave it to you all to be civil and even better than merely civil, Christian in your attitudes toward each other.
Remember "a person is an entity toward which the only acceptable attitude is love" (which is a certain Polish philosopher's way of stating the golden rule)
